# Disable Barchart Value Text in Achartengine on Android

Tags: android, achartengine

i want remove the barcharts each value text displayed on all bars on android and i am using achartengine. if u don't understand watch me below figure:

[image]

help me with greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to hide the chart values:

```
renderer.setDisplayChartValues(false);
```

Or, if you have a reference to an `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`:

```
int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i).setDisplayChartValues(false);
}
```

Comment: this not work it's shows warning: The method setDisplayChartValues(boolean) from the type XYMultipleSeriesRenderer is deprecated

Comment: @Dinesh In Dan's answer `renderer` is of type `SimpleSeriesRenderer`.

Comment: @Dheeraj V.S. ok but how get from XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to simpleseriesrender can u help me?

Comment: There is no setDisplayChartValues() on my XYMultipleSeriesRenderer!!

Comment: It is in its superclass DefaultRenderer.